# Does ruamel.yaml have a function to do the process with all files in one directory?

Tags: ruamel.yaml

Does ruamel.yaml have a function to do the process with all files in one directory?
Something like this:
`data = yaml.load(Path("*.*"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, but you can do it one line (assuming you have the imports and the `YAML()` instance):

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

data = [yaml.load(p) for p in Path('.').glob('*.yaml')]
```